# How to create sub domain from asp.net code

Tags: asp.net, dns

I need to create sub domain from code. For example my web site register new user named battulga. After automatically create battulga.mydomain.com. 
How to do this?

Comment: Who manages mydomain.com? With what nameserver software? How is the data from mydomain.com produced? (Dynamic Update on the master of mydomain.com is the obvious solution but it depends on many things.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a [thread](http://forums.asp.net/p/1267157/2384859.aspx) about this in ASP.net forum.

Comment: This thread does not mention the obvious solution: Dynamic Update on the DNS server. Difficult to say more without details from the OP.